# Search Wildcard('<', '>'), count it and get the position in java

Tags: java, android, string, wildcard

I want to search Wildcard('<', '>') in a string, count them and get their positions in java. My string is like below

> Peter <5554>, John <5556>,

which function should I use? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You  should use [Pattern](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) and [Matcher](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html):

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("<[^>]*>");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("Peter <5554>, John <5556>,");
while (matcher.find()) {
   System.out.println("index="+matcher.start()+" - "+matcher.group());
}
```

Output:

```
index=6 - <5554>
index=19 - <5556>
```

Comment: Nice solution, although the OP was not asking for postions of this pattern but for position of the `<` and `>` chars (but maybe you solved what he was *really* looking at ;) )

Comment: Thank you all. I use Pattern. =D True Soft, may i know more how to make regular expression?

Comment: See http://www.regular-expressions.info/. In this case, `<` means that you look after `<`; `[^>]` means a character that is not `>`; `*` is for zero or more characters, and `>` matches `>`. If your content is formed by one or more digits, you can use `<\d+>`. In java you must escape backslash: `"<\\d+>"`.

Answer (score 2):

One solution would be to use String.indexOf(). You can do something like this:

```
String s = "Peter <5554>, John <5556>";
List<Integer> posGt = new ArrayList<Integer>();
int i = 0;
while((i = s.indexOf('>', i)) != -1) {
   posGt.add(i++);
}
...
//the same for <
```

Answer (score 2):

You can implement it with repeated `indexOf` and `substring`:

```
String s = "Peter <5554>, John <5556>,"
int count = 0;
ArrayList<Integer> positions = new ArrayList<Integer>();
int cut = 0;
while(true) {
  // search for <
  int index = s.indexOf('<');
  if (index < 0)
    break;
  // search for >
  int index2 = s.indexOf('>');
  if (index2 < 0)
    break; // or throw exception

  // update count and positions
  count++;
  positions.add(index+cut);

  s = s.substring(index2+1);
  cut += index2+1; // used to compute the initial position since we're cutting the string
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Repeated `indexOf` with `fromIndex` looks like a nice solution. The alternative would have been iterating over the string and using `charAt` (arguably the obvious solution, if only java had sane string indexing):

```
String s = "Peter <5554>, John <5556>,";
for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
    if (s.charAt(i) == '<' || s.charAt(i) == '>') {
        System.out.printf("index %d - %s\n", i, s.charAt(i));
    }
}
```